# Output Format when Writing an Array to at Text File

Tags: python, numpy, file, csv

I am writing an array to a text file, as part of a larger project. I wrote a small code snippet:

```
import numpy as np
import csv

data99 = np.array([[1.,2.,3.],[4.,5.,6.],[7.,8.,9.],[10.,11.,12.]])


data98 = np.array([99,98,97,96])

for i in range(len(data98)):
    data99[i,2] = data98[i]

with open('zzz.txt', 'w') as ab:
    csv.writer(ab, delimiter = ',').writerows(data99)
```

It ouputs exactly the format I am looking for:

```
1.0,2.0,99.0

4.0,5.0,98.0

7.0,8.0,97.0

10.0,11.0,96.0
```

When I try to use the same write function in my larger project:

```
from PIL.TiffTags import TAGS

import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from math import sqrt

import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

import csv
# .
# .
# .
with open('Terrain_deviations.txt', 'w') as ab:
    csv.writer(ab, delimiter = ',').writerows(deviations)
```

The format coming out is different:

```
[[ 0.         20.         -9.55028766]]

[[ 0.        30.        -9.1716853]]

[[ 0.         40.         -9.02336858]]

[[ 0.         50.         -8.91502989]]

[[ 0.         60.         -8.61375907]]
```

These are both arrays of float64's.
data99 is (4,3)
deviations is (2324,3)

[Screenshot of Variable Explorer from Spyder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZ6T2.png)

Comment: Do you have to use numpy? What do you mean "The format coming out is different", where is it coming out different? In python, the csv file or when loading the csv file back into your program?

Comment: `data99` is a (4,3) array of numbers.  What is `deviations`?

Comment: deviations is a (2324,3) array of numbers (float 64)

Comment: I don't have to use numpy. I am new to Python, and based on what I have found in tutorials and online examples, that is what I have found to get me this far.

Comment: In the case of data99, it wrote to the file with no brackets and there is a "," between values. In the case of deviations, there are brackets around each row of the array, and there are no ","s between the values, just spaces.